# Dynamodb: Why can't a primary key be part of a filter-expression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Let's say we have a table with `item`s that has an attribute `userId` (partition-key, string) and an attribute `creationTime` (sort-key, number). I would like to execute a query that fetches a user's items from time `t1` to time `t2` on a secondary-index.

Since I can't have multiple range conditions on the same item, my idea was to add a filtering expression to limit the results:

`aws dynamodb query --table-name items --index-name userId-creationTime-index --key-condition-expression "userId=:u AND creationTime<=:t1" --filter-expression "creationTime>=:t2" --expression-attribute-values '{":u":{"S":"6f3b581d-8632-4edc-a19d-b77f158d8a23"}, ":t1":{"N":"1456647476000000"}, ":t2":{"N":"1456561076000000"}}'`

The query fails with

`A client error (ValidationException) occurred when calling the Query operation: Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: creationTime`

This feels very strange. Isn't filtering just about limiting the result  *after* the execution of the query? Isn't it possible to implement a condition like `t1 <= creationDate <= t2` like this?

Comment: Figured out a workaround using the BETWEEN operator. However, if anyone can explain why I can't use the same attribute in a filtering expression it would be great!

Comment: Amazon rep says it's "[for the benefit of users.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172530)" It still isn't very clear why the user is limited from using all of the conditional operators (that are available in filter expressions) in key condition expressions.

Comment: When you say secondary indexes do you mean Local secondary indexes? Because that seems possible in this example.

http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Querying

Comment: This was for a GSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB will first read a page of your items sequentially from the host storing your data. The key condition listed above is used to limit the data read from the host where your items are stored. Next, it will filter the results read from the storage host based on the filter parameters you provide. RCU are incurred for actual read volume on the storage hosts. By using KeyConditions for primary key attributes and Filter expressions for everything else, you can better control the read cost of your query operations. Having tighter conditions on the KeyCondition of a query operation will limit the number of items read, reducing the RCU consumed in each query operation.